# When I upload a file using an html form and php can I also pass the file to a java applet?

Tags: java, php, html, file-upload, applet

I have a java program that analyses images. I want to make the program available in a web-browser.

The program requires an image file from the user. With a regular java program this is not a problem, as you have access to the user's file system. However this is not the case in an applet. My plan was to have the user upload the image to my server with an html form and a php program. This has the added benefit of storing the photos for use on the site.

It is advisable to put the image in a directory above the webroot for security reasons. However, this means that the applet will not have access to the image. Is there a way to send the image to the server and to the applet? For security reasons I would like to avoid having a program that sends files that are outside of the webroot. I would also like to avoid unsightly security warnings. Is there another way to approach this project?

The following is the php code that I am using for the upload:

```
<?php

// the current directory
$current_directory = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

// the location of the program and uploads the file
$uploadProgram = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self . 'webuploadcode.php';

// the maximum file size in bytes for the html upload form
$maximum_file_size = 300000; 

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>Upload form</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="Upload" action="<?php echo $uploadProgram ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <h1>Upload form</h1>
    <p>Logged in as: <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] ?></p>
    <p><input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $maximum_file_size ?>"></p>
    <p>
        <label for="file">Select a file to upload:</label>
        <input id="file" type="file" name="file">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="submit">Click to </label>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File">
    </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php  

// the directory to receieve the files
$upload_directory = '../../photouploads/';

// the location of the upload form in case we need it
$upload_form = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self .     'webuploadform.php';

// the location of the status page
$upload_status = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self .     'uploadstatus.php';

// name of the fieldname used for the file in the HTML form
$fieldname = 'file';

$username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];

// possible PHP upload errors
$errors = array(1 => 'php.ini max file size exceeded', 
                2 => 'html form max file size exceeded', 
                3 => 'file upload was only partial', 
                4 => 'no file was attached');

// check the upload form was actually submitted else print form
isset($_POST['submit']) or error('the upload form is needed', $upload_form);

// check for standard uploading errors
($_FILES[$fieldname]['error'] == 0) or error($errors[$_FILES[$fieldname]['error']], $upload_form);

// check that the file we are working on really was an HTTP upload
@is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name']) or error('not an HTTP upload', $upload_form);

// blacklist php files
$blacklist = array(".php", ".phtml", ".php3", ".php4");

foreach ($blacklist as $item)
{ 
    if(preg_match("/$item\$/i", $_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name']))
    { 
        echo "We do not allow uploading PHP files.\n";
        exit;
    }
}

// check the size of the image to confirm that it is an image file 
@getimagesize($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name']) or error('only image uploads are allowed', $upload_form);

// make a unique filename for the uploaded file 
$now = time();
//$_POST['credit']
while(file_exists($uploadFilename = $upload_directory.$now.'-'.$username.'.jpg'))
{ 
    $now++;
}

// move the file to the image folder and allocate it with the new filename
@move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'], $uploadFilename)
    or error('receiving directory insuffiecient permission', $upload_form);

// Redirect the client to the status page
header('Location: ' . $uploadStatus);

// an error handler which will be used if the upload fails
function error($error, $location, $seconds = 5)
{
    header("Refresh: $seconds; URL=\"$location\"");
    echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"'."\n".
    '"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">'."\n\n".
    '<html lang="en">'."\n".
    '   <head>'."\n".
    '       <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-    8859-1">    '."\n\n".
    '       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">    '."\n\n".
    '   <title>Upload error</title>'."\n\n".
    '   </head>'."\n\n".
    '   <body>'."\n\n".
    '   <div id="Upload">'."\n\n".
    '       <h1>Upload failure</h1>'."\n\n".
    '       <p>An error has occured: '."\n\n".
    '       <span class="red">' . $error . '...</span>'."\n\n".
    '       The upload form is reloading</p>'."\n\n".
    '    </div>'."\n\n".
    '</html>';
    exit;
} // end error handler

?>
```

Comment: What security concerns are you referring to in your design? If you need to serve the images back to the user via the Applet, put them in an accessible web location. Also, you can read images from the users local file system if you sign your Applet.

Comment: The security concerns pertain to a malicious user uploading code (instead of an image) and hacking the site, and reading password files and such that are stored above the webroot. Obviously both uploading and reading must be handled carefully. Not being particularly experienced with such things I am being cautious.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a java program that analyses images. I want to make the program available in a web-browser.

Launch a [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) from a link using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Apps. launched using JWS have access to the [JNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jnlp/info) API.  The JNLP API offers the [`FileContents`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/FileContents.html) object to allow even sand-boxed apps. to open files from, and save files to, the local file system.  Here is a [demo. of the file services](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs).

When sand-boxed, the action to pop a file browser will invoke a security prompt like this (taken from the linked demo.).

[image: Security prompt from sand-boxed demo. when opening file]

---

JWS can also be used to launch embedded applets in a Plug-In 2 JRE.

---

If digitally signed by the developer, and trusted when prompted by the end user, a trusted applet can access the more common `JFileChooser`/`File`.

---

Is the image *required* on the server at all?  If not, save yourselves the bandwidth and trouble.  If it is, the applet/JWS app. can upload it after doing sanity checks (e.g. on size in bytes, dimensions etc.).

Comment: Thank for the comments. It is a sandboxed app and thus it is my understanding that JNLP will prompt the user about the file. I wish to avoid such prompts. I do want the image on the server, but it is not needed for the image analysis program. I just wanted to both upload the image and analyze it in one go.

Comment: *"JNLP will prompt the user about the file."*  Of course,  at the very moment the user/app. goes to pop the JNLP file browser, the user will be asked WTE *"This app. wants to load resources from the local file system.  Allow?"*  If the user invoked the dialog, why on earth would they refuse at that point?

Comment: A JWS is certainly an option, and you are correct that a user probably would not refuse at that point. However, I wish to avoid the prompts. They do not create the type of user experience that I wish my site and programs to have.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use applet to load the file, then have the applet upload it to the server.
Other, less desirable, option is to upload the file to server using HTTP post then have the applet download it from the server.

Comment: Why is the latter less desirable? Do both options have the same security risk? I would assume that there is a greater risk by allowing a app running on someone else's computer to upload files to the server.

Comment: Because the latter entails 2 transfers of file (to and from server) while the former means one file transfer (from applet to server).